# Is there a way to construct 3D array from 2D array in python using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary, tensor

I've got a matrix that values are positive integers and want to find the bit representation unpacked into a tensor using `numpy`

e.g

```
[[1 , 2],
 [3 , 4]]
```

to

```
[[0 , 0],
 [0 , 1]], 

[[0 , 1],
 [1 , 0]],

[[1 , 0],
 [1 , 0]]
```

Comment: What is the logic with the binary tensor's values?

Comment: Actually I want to map a 2D array that its entries are decimal to binary tensor. In this case tensor is 3 - 2D arrays with binary entries

Comment: depth of tensor is depend on length of max entry , in this case 4 is max entry so 4 equals 100 then depth is 3

Comment: Something like `np.unpackbits(x[None,:], axis=0)[-3:]` should do the job.

Comment: That's right I looked it but it doesn't support custom unit length. it just works with unit8

Comment: @obchardon - your solution works brilliantly for `uint8`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is limited to 2D arrays but works with elements larger than `np.uint8` and calculates the necessary bit depth.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4]])
bits = int(np.log2(M.max())) + 1

(np.where(
     M.reshape(-1,1) & 2**np.arange(bits)[::-1], 1, 0)
   .reshape(*M.shape, -1)
   .transpose(2,0,1))
```

Output

```
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 0]]])
```

---

### How this works

Construct a range with powers of 2

```
2**np.arange(bits)[::-1]
```

Broadcast this range with `logical_and` over the input elements

```
(M.reshape(-1,1) & 2**np.arange(bits)[::-1])
```

Output

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [4, 0, 0]])
```

Convert to `1`,`0` bool array with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
array([[0, 0, 1],   # 1 in binary
       [0, 1, 0],   # 2 in binary
       [0, 1, 1],   # 3 in binary
       [1, 0, 0]])  # 4 in binary
```

Shape to desired output.

Comment: Thanks . That's really useful for me :D